# ChartJS labels along the edges

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to distribute X labels proportionately, with obligatory have them in the very left and right edges?

```
scales: {
    xAxes: {
      grid: { display: false },
      ticks: { autoSkip: true, maxTicksLimit: 5, maxRotation: 0, minRotation: 0 },
    },
```

[image]

```
 scales: {
    xAxes: {
      grid: { display: false },
      ticks: { autoSkip: true, maxTicksLimit: 5, maxRotation: 0, minRotation: 0 },
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'month',
      },
    },
```

[image]

Comment: By the position of the labels I'd guess you haven't set your x scale as `type: "time"` (see [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis)) but left it as the default `type: "category"`.

Comment: @kikon yes you're right. With scale type = time is better, but still not that I need,

Comment: chart js doesn't support this by default

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [axes callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks) to
set uncommon/not covered properties, but by doing so you forfeit some of the services and protections built in the scales code. In particular, if the chart is static and you are sure that tick labels will never overlap, you could use `afterBuildTicks` callback to set the ticks positions of a time scale - the position of a tick is  its `value` property, in unix timestamp.

Here's an example:

```js
const d0 = new Date('2021-09-01').valueOf(),
    d1 = new Date('2023-09-10').valueOf(),
    N = 100;

const labels1 = Array.from({length: N}, (_, i) => {
    return d0 + (d1-d0)/(N-1)*i;
});
const data = {
    labels: labels1,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Bars',
            data: Array.from({length: N}, (_, i) => Math.random() < 0.4 && i !== 0 && i !== N-1 ? 0 : 5 + Math.random() * 10),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(128, 196, 32, 0.85)',
        },
        {
            label: 'Line',
            type: 'line',
            data: Array.from({length: N}, (_, i) => 5 + i/N * 10 + Math.random() / 2),
            fill: true,
            pointRadius: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5)',
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales:{
            x:{
                type: 'time',
                grid: { display: false },
                time:{
                    unit: "day",
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'MMM yyyy'
                    }
                },
                  ticks: {autoSkip: true, maxTicksLimit: 5, //stepSize: (d1-d0)/4/3600/1000/24,
                    maxRotation: 0, minRotation: 0
                },
                min: d0 - 5*24*36e5, // add a margin of 5 days to make sure the data fits
                max: d1 + 5*24*36e5,

                afterBuildTicks(scale){
                    const nTicks = scale.options.ticks.maxTicksLimit ?? 10;
                    scale.ticks = Array.from({length: nTicks}, (_, i)=>({value: (d1-d0)/(nTicks-1)*i+d0}));
                }
            },
            y:{
                display: false
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: ''
            }
        }
    },
};

new Chart('chart1', config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@^1"></script>

  <div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
  </div>
```